# React Datepicker RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

My datepicker is throwing `RangeError: Invalid time value` while trying to set selected date value which i am getting from API as string value.

My API date string is `12.09.2020`

```
<DatePicker dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={currentFuelPrice.date_of_sale} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
```

After react 2.0 version, datepicker wont support date as string, it said to use date-fns parseiso...

```
import { parseISO } from 'date-fns'; 

currentFuelPrice.date_of_sale = parseISO(response.data.date_of_sale, 1);
```

after adding parseISO, i am still getting  error `RangeError: Invalid time value`

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: Which version of DatePicker are you using ?

Comment: react version 16.13.1

Comment: datepicker 3.1.3

Comment: did you do this: selected={Date.parse('12/09/2020')} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parse method to achieve your goal. It's accepting date string, format and reference date. Here you can use like this:

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-feynman-k75i4?file=/src/App.js:0-639

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import { parse } from "date-fns";

export default function App() {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <DatePicker
        dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setStartDate(parse("12.09.2020", "dd.MM.yyyy", new Date()))
        }
      >
        Set Api DATE
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it is working perfectly. after adding parse method..it was my mistake not added startdate to datepicker as selected value..